# Unable to edit duplicate lists from the first questions review queue, after closing a duplicate question

Tags: support, review, duplicate-questions, dupehammer

As a gold tag badge holder, I have the ability to unilaterally close questions (with those tags) as duplicates and, by extension, I also have the ability to edit the duplicate links on those questions.

Sometimes when reviewing questions, I come across questions that I believe should be closed as duplicates. Closing a question within the review queue [used to give an error message and invalidate the review task](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/411600/15497888). However, this seems to no longer be the case as I can now submit the review after closing without any issue.

Currently, however, from within the review queue, there is no option to edit to add duplicate targets to the list, which means if I select the wrong duplicate target, or want to add additional targets (close it as a duplicate of multiple questions), it can't be done easily.

This is a screenshot of what the review task looks like immediately after voting to close from within review queue:
[image: First Questions Review Queue task with close banner but no edit button]

To edit the list of duplicates I have to leave the review queue to go to the question page and click edit button from there:

[image: Question close banner view outside of review queue showing the edit button circled in red]

Is there a way to edit the duplicates list from within review queue? And, if not, could it be added?

Comment: How did you get to this view? Did you close it from the review queue? Did you hit "back" to go to the review after closing it? I'm kinda confused how you were shown a review for a question you'd just closed. :)

Comment: Yes @Catija. I closed the question from within review queue. I was served the question within the queue, I edited the question, checked the answers tab saw the answer from the OP, went back to the question tab hit the close button (still within review queue) found a dupe target and copied in the duplicate link and hit "Vote to Close". The question was then closed (I'm still within the review queue at this point). I then went to add a link to the targets list but noticed there was no edit button. This is when I took the screenshot.

Answer (score 2):

When you close a question (either unilaterally as a gold tag-badge holder or moderator, or as the final 'normal' close voter) from the First Questions queue, the post appears to go into a strange "meta state" – allowing you to complete the review *via* the "Other action" button.

After the first incarnation of the new Review UI, once a question was closed, the FQ review was *immediately* invalidated and, thus, a reviewer who closed it could not complete the review. This caused much consternation among reviewers, so the issue was "fixed". Presumably, when in this "meta state", the full UI for the "closed-as-duplicate" banner isn't (yet?) fully operational.

Note that, after you have closed the question, refreshing the page (while staying in the active review) will prevent you from completing the review – but it will likely also allow you to edit the duplicate list.

Comment: I was aware that refreshing would invalidate the review. I haven't come across a review today to invalidate to test if edit is available if the review is invalidated rather than completed. That said, going back to the review in question there is [no edit button on that page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FOdK0.png) even when not in the in-between state.